# How to use Curl in PS

Tags: powershell

I do not know how to use Curl in PowerShell.

PHP Curl looks:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "link");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Key: " . $apiPublic,
    "Sign: " . $snt_header
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

I tried everything using:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri link`
                  -Method 'Post'`
                  -Headers @( "Key:$apiPublic", "Sign:$sntHeader")`
                  -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Comment: What have you tried in Powershell using `Invoke-RestMethod` and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod -Uri link -Method 'Post' -Headers @( "Key:$apiPublic", "Sign:$sntHeader") -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you have any error? Do you not receive any response back?

Comment: Please add your error message to your question.

Comment: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

Comment: Could you just tell me how to translate that Curl PHP to PS format , please ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The error was : Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary'
 required by parameter 'Headers'.

Comment: Besides, All errors in PS shows in russian language. So, I don't know how can I say what exactly error it is.

Comment: It says somehing like cannot convert. Unsupported method

Comment: When Im trying this: $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Key",$apiPublic)
$headers.Add("Sign",$sntHeader)
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://dsx.uk/tapi/v2/info/account -Method 'Post' -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   I got Connection is closed. Undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = 'https://dsx.uk/tapi/v2/info/account'
$headers = @{
    'key' = 'foo'
    'sign' = 'bar'
}
$body = @{
    value= "baz"
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
$result
```

> If you have gotten the "Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection
>   was closed:  An unexpected error occurred on a send." Add the line below to your script as Powershell uses TLS1.0 for web request by default. However if the server is expecting 1.2 you need to tell Powershell to use 1.2 instead

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: Hasta, after I put the Tls12 the errors changed Now I got Server error 400 Even if I put just $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri

Comment: Hasta, we did it! :) The problem was incorrect -Body value. I fixed it and finally got response from the server. Thank you!

Comment: Oh that value was meant to be an example only. Anyway well done..